# Nativescript/Angular app crashes when trying to dynamically update Listview template with nsTemplateKey

Tags: angular, listview, nativescript

In my Nativescript / Angular app I use a listview to show an array (name, key)

```
<ListView #lvid [items]="myarray" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" height="800" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector">
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="3" let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
        <GridLayout height="auto" columns="180,100" backgroundColor="cornsilk">
          <Label col="0" row="{{i+1}}" [text]="item.name" class="h3"></Label>
          <Label col="1" row="{{i+1}}" [text]="item.key" class="h3"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="4" let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
      <GridLayout height="auto" columns="180,100" backgroundColor="lightgreen">
        <Label col="0" row="{{i+1}}" [text]="item.name" class="h3"></Label>
        <Label col="1" row="{{i+1}}" [text]="item.key" class="h3"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
```

My template selector is trivial, it returns simply the item.key (which is a number) as string:

```
    templateSelector(item: Lebensmittel, index: number, items: any) {
        return item.key.toString();
    }
```

Everything works fine and my rows are formatted based on the key.
Now I implemented a modal dialog which is started when a row is tapped (onItemTap) which allows me to change the content of a row.
So far so good, works also. Content is directly update as I use data binding.
As the template was not automatically changed when I change the key, I thought to use the refresh-method of my listview to trigger a re-draw.

```
    onItemTap(args: ItemEventData) {

        let options:ModalDialogOptions = {
            context: {props: this.myarray[args.index]},
            fullscreen: false,
            viewContainerRef: this.VcRef
        };
        this.modal.showModal(InputDialogComponent, options).then (response => {
                this.myarray[args.index] = response;
                let mylv = <ListView>this.listView.nativeElement;
                mylv.refresh();
            }
       });
    }
```

Now I face the problem that the app crashes when I change the key which should trigger a change of the template:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method getView failed
System.err: Error: There is no entry with key 'org.nativescript.widgets.GridLayout{f621101 V.E...... ........ 0,0-320,51}' in the realized views cache for template with key'4'.
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: ZoneAwareError(file: node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:1298:0)
System.err:     at ListViewAdapter.getView(file: node_modules\@nativescript\core\ui\list-view\list-view.android.js:243:0)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
```

In that example, the key was "3" and I changed it to "4", therefore it complains

> There is no entry with key
>   'org.nativescript.widgets.GridLayout{f621101 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-320,51}' in the realized views cache for template with key'4'.

My suspicion is, that the templates are assigned to the rows initially and can't be changed afterwards.
I thought a refresh() would trigger also a reassingment of the templates - obviously not.

What do I miss?

Thanks in advance
Christof